# Finding equivalent boolean functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using only the operators ⇒ (conditional) and ∼ (negation) my book says that
p ∧ q = ~(p  ⇒  ~q) and p ∨ q = ~p ⇒  q

Why is that so? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated since there's no explanation on my book.

Comment: What is the definition you have been given for $ \Rightarrow $ ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: What have you been told about $ \Rightarrow $ 's behaviour as a Boolean function?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvpyg.png here's the page. there's no explanation, it's just a table

Comment: You where not given a truth table for conditional?

Answer (score 1):

You an show this with truth tables.

```
p | q | p and q | ~q  | p => ~q | ~(p => ~q) | p ∧ q = ~(p => ~q)
T | T | T       | F   | F       | T          | T
T | F | F       | T   | T       | F          | T
F | T | F       | F   | T       | F          | T
F | F | F       | T   | T       | F          | T
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a truth table for $p$ and $q$ should help you understand this.